# Help with opencv random error

Tags: ros, opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

So I have been working with opencv and ros to do object detection and everything seemed to be fine until the other day and suddenly when i start using the SURF detection line of code I get this error.

/home/frank/catkin_ws/devel/lib/bingo_detection/bingo_detection_server: symbol lookup error: /home/frank/catkin_ws/devel/lib/bingo_detection/bingo_detection_server: undefined symbol: *ZNK2cv9Feature2D7computeERKNS_3MatERSt6vectorINS_8KeyPointESaIS5_EERS1*

I have no idea what I did.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185568/help-with-opencv-random-error/) by [TT](https://answers.ros.org/users/19594/tt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out,

It was an issue with the CMakeList.txt and the OpenCV libraries. I had originally had the CMakeLists.txt addtarget to specific folder inside my project which had the opencv libraries. But for whatever reason when i did an update it would no longer let me do this so i just needed to remove

${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libopencv_core.so
And all others...

and replace with

${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}

And that fixed the problem

---

Originally posted by [TT](https://answers.ros.org/users/19594/tt/) with karma: 16 on 2014-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ccapriotti](https://answers.ros.org/users/18779/ccapriotti/) on 2014-07-08**:
@TT: can you post your system specifics, like Linux distro, hardware platform, etc ? Since this is solved, we might as well document it; Might can help other souls going through the same calvary. I will vote you answer right, since you with your current karma points may not be able to do so.